How to combine two validation_rules?
I have the following piece of json that is working as expected :
    {
      "name": "end_time",
      "display_name": "sdp.admin.operatinghours.workingtime.endtime",
      "relational_mapping": "ChargesTable.TS_ENDTIME",
      "type": "datetime",
      "display_type":"Date/Time",
      "default": "$(created_time)",
      "validation_rules":[{
        "field":"end_time.value",
        "on": ["add","edit_with_diff","edit"],
        "value": "$(THIS_WEEK)",
        "condition": "IS",
        "error_code": "90001"
      }]
    },

I needed to create another validation_rule and I need them to act logically as an AND. Here is my other validation_rule within the same block of code, working as expected.
    {
      "name": "end_time",
      "display_name": "sdp.admin.operatinghours.workingtime.endtime",
      "relational_mapping": "ChargesTable.TS_ENDTIME",
      "type": "datetime",
      "display_type":"Date/Time",
      "default": "$(created_time)",
      "validation_rules":[{"field": "owner.value","value":["Jimmy Choo"],"condition": "neq"}]
    },

But, now, need to combine both validation_rules into the single block code but haven't been successful. Does anyone have any ideas?
